# Can I always see my inbox first?

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange

I would like to see my **inbox** first instead of the **hot questions**. Is there a way I can fix this?

It's really annoying. Really!

[image]

Comment: BTW, Inbox will be shown automatically whenever you have an item awaiting to be read.

Comment: @MarcoCeppi I know but if I have let's say 3 items and I click on the first I read it and then I want to look at the next one I click on **stackExchange** again. But now I just see the news! It's really frustrating! :(

Comment: Just go to http://askubuntu.com/inbox - BOOM PROBLEM SOLVED BRO.

Comment: See also the same request on MSO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86342/can-the-stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-default-to-inbox-rather-th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86347

This answer answers my question and I see the point of the way it's designed.